# Validar CPF - Linguagem C

Tags: c, números-aleatórios

Preciso gerar um cpf aleatório e válido para um trabalho da faculdade

Este é o código que desenvolvi até agora, ele está gerando letras ao invés de números nos dois dígitos verificadores

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char cpf[15];
    int i;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++) cpf[i] = (rand() % 10 + '0');
    cpf[3] = '.';
    cpf[7] = '.';
    cpf[11] = '-';
    cpf[12] = ((((cpf[0] * 10) + (cpf[1] * 9) + (cpf[2] * 8) + (cpf[4] * 7) + (cpf[5] * 6) + (cpf[6] * 5) + (cpf[8] * 4) + (cpf[9] * 3) + (cpf[10] * 2)) % 11) + '0');
    cpf[13] = ((((cpf[0] * 11) + (cpf[1] * 10) + (cpf[2] * 9) + (cpf[4] * 8) + (cpf[5] * 7) + (cpf[6] * 6) + (cpf[8] * 5) + (cpf[9] * 4) + (cpf[10] * 3) + (cpf[12] * 2)) % 11) + '0');
    cpf[15] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s", cpf);
}
```

Comment: Você está multiplicando o código que representa o caractere e não o valor numérico que este caractere representa (para cada cpf[i] subtraia '0' para multiplicar) e, além disso, não testou se o resto da divisão é >= 10.

Comment: Veja se este artigo pode ajudar: https://medium.com/dev-interior/checagem-de-cpf-em-c-a64fe7a386f5

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?
Então, o programa estava exibindo letras nos dígitos verificadores pois as multiplicações estavam sendo feitas com caracteres ao invés de inteiros.

Uma solução "simples" para isso é diminuir `'0'` de cada multiplicação feita (o que transformará os caracteres em inteiros):

```c
dig = ((((cpf[0] - '0') * 10) + ((cpf[1] - '0') * 9) + ((cpf[2] - '0') * 8) + ((cpf[4] - '0') * 7) + ((cpf[5] - '0') * 6) + ((cpf[6] - '0') * 5) + ((cpf[8] - '0') * 4) + ((cpf[9] - '0') * 3) + ((cpf[10] - '0') * 2)) % 11);
```

Depois disso, analisamos então o **resto** dessa divisão (armazenado na variável `dig`):

Segundo o cálculo do dígito verificador, se o **resto** for 0 ou 1, o dígito `cpf[12]` será `'0'` (zero). Caso seja 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ou 10, o dígito `cpf[12]` será `(11 - dig) + '0'`

```c
if(dig == 0 || dig == 1){
        cpf[12] = '0';
}
    else{
        cpf[12] = (11 - dig) + '0';
}
```

O mesmo processo se repete para o segundo dígito verificador.

Enfim, o código completo ficaria assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char cpf[15];
    int i;
    int dig;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        cpf[i] = (rand() % 10) + '0';
    }
    cpf[3] = '.';
    cpf[7] = '.';
    cpf[11] = '-';
    dig = ((((cpf[0] - '0') * 10) + ((cpf[1] - '0') * 9) + ((cpf[2] - '0') * 8) + ((cpf[4] - '0') * 7) + ((cpf[5] - '0') * 6) + ((cpf[6] - '0') * 5) + ((cpf[8] - '0') * 4) + ((cpf[9] - '0') * 3) + ((cpf[10] - '0') * 2)) % 11);
    if(dig == 0 || dig == 1){
        cpf[12] = '0';
    }
    else{
        cpf[12] = (11 - dig) + '0';
    }
    dig = ((((cpf[0] - '0') * 11) + ((cpf[1] - '0') * 10) + ((cpf[2] - '0') * 9) + ((cpf[4] - '0') * 8) + ((cpf[5] - '0') * 7) + ((cpf[6] - '0') * 6) + ((cpf[8] - '0') * 5) + ((cpf[9] - '0') * 4) + ((cpf[10] - '0') * 3) + ((cpf[12] - '0') * 2)) % 11);
    if(dig == 0 || dig == 1){
        cpf[13] = '0';
    }
    else{
        cpf[13] = (11 - dig) + '0';
    }
    cpf[15] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s \n", cpf);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite,o seu problema é bem simples de ser resolvido.

Os caracteres numéricos de um campo de CPF vão de 0 a 9
quando for utilizar o srand(), utilize:

````
```
 srand() % 9 + '0'
```
````

Assim o seu número aleatório ficará entre 0 e 9. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Isso não irá gerar um CPF, apenas uma sequência de números aleatórios. O CPF tem regras de validação...

Comment: O resto da divisão de um inteiro por 9 dará como resultado um número entre 0 e 8. Afinal 9 / 9 dá como resultado 1 com resto 0.